# How to create a Drupal view that filters by author of a referenced entity?

Tags: drupal, drupal-views

I'm trying to create a Drupal Views view on a shopping cart website. The shopping cart contains various product nodes that each reference an image node with an entityreference. Contractors create images which are then approved and added to new product nodes.

I want this view to appear in a block on pages for product nodes. I want this view to show a selection of product nodes that reference images created by the artist who created the image referenced by the product node on whose page the block appears.

Getting Views to display links to products based on an attribute of a referenced entity on other nodes that matches an attribute of a referenced entity on the current node is proving to be beyond my current ability with Views. I'm getting tangled up in contextual filters and relationships that never seem to return anything at all, most of the time. Am I barking up the wrong tree?

It is important that I create this view without using raw PHP code for the contextual filter or anywhere else entered through the web interface. I would be able to write a custom "glue" module if I must but I'm running short on time and hook_views_data() seems somewhat recalcitrant to my current experiments.

Comment: 1. Create a view of nodes with a filter on the bundle you want to display. 2. Add a relationship to the image node via the entity reference field 3. Add a filter/contextual filter as normal, choose the author field, and set it to use the related node, not the original one. 4. Drink tea

Comment: Unfortunately, that gives me all of the product nodes in the system, since all products are created by admin and only the author of the images are different. At least, that is if I choose "Provide default value" => "User ID from the URL", "Use node author". Any other option either gives me every node in the system or no nodes at all.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using [Viewfield](https://drupal.org/project/viewfield) to insert my view into every product node with the entityreference field's author's UID as an argument token. I then modified my view to use a contextual filter on the raw value provided with a relationship based on the entityreference field. I also filtered it to only show product nodes. This seems to do the trick, more or less.